# Bound for inverse of gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that
$$G(z):= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{-z}}{n!}z(z+1)\cdots(z+n)$$
is the inverse of the Gamma function for $\operatorname{Re}z>0$, and something I need to do is bound $1/G(z)$ in the interval $x\in[1,2)$, where $x$ is the real part of $z$.

Currently I have reached the point where
$$\begin{align*}
|1/G(z)|&=\frac{n!}{|n^{-z}|\cdot |z||z+1|\cdots|z+n|}\\
&\leq \frac{n!}{n^{-x}\cdot (x)(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}\\
&\leq\frac{n!}{n^{-2}(n+1)!}\\
&=\frac{n^2}{n+1},
\end{align*}$$
which doens't seem bounded as $n$ grows. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why the complicated $G(z)$ stuff? Isn't $1/G(z)$ by your definition simply $\Gamma(z)$?

Comment: @vitamind I know that is the case, but in the way the material has been developed, I haven't proved it yet.

Comment: 1. Already the second inequality diverges. 2.  Find another lower bound of $x(x+1)(x+2)...$. [Not too low, not $(n+1)!]$

Comment: @vitamind If $x\in[1,2)$, how would I be able to do better than $(n+1)!$ as a lower bound?

Comment: Do you have to find an upper bound for Gamma by using this definition?

Comment: Yes, I have to show that $1/G(z)$ satisfies the Wielandt theorem.